# Case when equivalent of bucketing users when buckets aren't mutually exclusive?

Tags: sql

What is the best way to bucket data into categories in SQL when the buckets aren't necessarily mutually exclusive?

When using normal case when statements, data is bucketed in the first category that it qualifies for and is not considered in other buckets further down the case when statement it could also qualify for. I want to be able to bucket data into all possible categories.

For example, let's say we have string 'ABC'. I want to categorize this string using buckets 'String contains A','String contains B',' String contains D'. My code would similar to the below:

```
Select case 
when string like '%A%' then 'String_Contains_A'
when string like '%B%' then 'String_Contains_B'
when string like '%D%' then 'String_Contains_D'
else 'Other'
end as bucket,
String 
from datatable 
where string = 'ABC'
```

From how I understand it now, it seems that the string 'ABC' would only be categorized with the bucket 'String_Contains_A', but not with 'String_Contains_B'. What is the most efficient way to categorize the string under both bucket 'String_Contains_A' and 'String_Contains_B'. Thank you!

Comment: Edit your question and provide specific data and desired results.

Comment: How would this look is say the record for 'orange' was in both the bucket for 'red' and the bucket for 'yellow'? Would it be split to two records in your output? Would it be comma delimited with both buckets? To Gordon's point, some sample data and your desired results for that sample data would help immensely here.

Comment: It has been edited. Sorry for the formatting. First post and trying to fix now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A union query would work

```
select 'bucket1' bucket, other fields
from etc
where whatever
union all
select 'bucket2' bucket, other fields
from etc
where whatever
etc
```

Comment: I was hoping OP would explain what their output would look like, but I agree that this is most probably what they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flags instead of names:

```
Select string,
       (case when string like '%A%' then 1 else 0 end) as String_Contains_A,
       (case when string like '%B%' then 1 else 0 end) as String_Contains_B,
       (case when string like '%D%' then 1 else 0 end) as String_Contains_D
from datatable 
where string = 'ABC';
```